# how to customize display value in stackedbar chart in fusion chart?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I am using fusion charts in my application. I want to show custom text in stacked bar chart. Normally it displays what we have given in `value` attribute but I want to display some more text into brackets with it. However I can add static text for all bars using `numberSuffix` attribute provided by fusion charts itself.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3H2G/458/)

Can anyone please tell me how to add different suffix for each bars in stackedBar chart?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is the solution to your problem, I don't have time to apply this to your solution, but I think you won't have a problem with that: http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/tfo8x6Ls/4/ , if this suits than I will be glad to post some decent answer to your question afterwards

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know about this but can't implement this complex calculation just to show a single value for each bars. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered applying the attribute `displayValue`

```
{
    "label": "Bakersfield Central",
    "value": "880000",
    "displayValue": "My Custom text"
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3H2G/465/)